# How to fix adding two outputs of functions and then implementing the combined output to a text file in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I have been trying to combine 2 function's output all together and then printing the combined output of the functions in a text file. But the problem is that i am getting several errors, and if there is no error then it shows the output of one function only. Please fix this thing...

`pyhtml.py`

```
    import sys
    sys.setrecursionlimit(1500)


    def text(a):
        with open("index.txt", "w+") as s:
            s.write("<html>\n <h1>" + a + "</h1>\n</html>")


    def para(a):
        with open("index.txt", "w+") as x:
            x.write("\n <p1>" + a + "</p1>\n")
```

`index.py`

```
    from pyhtml import *

    text("hello")
    para("hello")
```

Please try to combine the output of these two functions in the index.txt file. In my case only one output is showing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change the `w+` to `a` as append instead of write.

The `w+` overwrites the file in every `open` but `a` creates the file if it does not exist and if it exists `a` appends the text into it.

**In your case:**

`with open("index.txt", "a") as s:`

**Content of index.txt:**

```
<html>
 <h1>hello</h1>
</html>
 <p1>hello</p1>
```

Comment: Hey, really thanks @milanbalazs. It really worked. But as i am running this file it is printing hello world again and again as much as i am running the file... Please provide a solution to this, where it will type/write it once.

Comment: You are welcome! If you use only these codes which are mentioned in your question then I mustn't run more then twice. There is no loop in that implementation. I have also tested it and both of functions run only once and provides the output which I have mentioned in my answer. If you have more code then please update your question or write a comment here.